# Как правильно написать афоризм?

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно написать афоризим?
1) Глупо есть быку с паханного им поля.
2) Глупо есть быку с вспаханного им поля.
И может вообще с одной Н пишется! Как правильно?

Comment: А какова мораль? Может быть, "глупо есть быка (с учётом вспаханного им поля)" - неблагодарно по отношению к трудолюбивому животному и недальновидно (может ещё одно вспахать)? Или смысл в том, что быку нужно быть умнее - сначала травки поесть, потом в плуг впрягаться?

Comment: Мораль такова, что человек ценит товары ручного труда, а не автоматезированного.

Comment: Мало кто догадается без расшифровки :)

Comment: Ну, он(афоризм) наталкивает на размышления.

Comment: Может быть, здесь нечто философское: Глупо пытаться найти то, что ты сам же уничтожил. Например, воспитывая в детях послушание во всем, не надо надеяться, что они вырастут творческими людьми.

Comment: Денис, я так понял, что Вы это афоризм, сами и придумали. Тогда Вам и решать, как его написать. Впрочем, в любом случае мне не кажется это удачной находкой.

Comment: В полной мере с Вами согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, оба варианта подойдут:

(1) Глупо есть быку с паханного им поля.  Две буквы НН в причастии при наличии зависимого слова.

(2) Глупо есть быку со вспаханного им поля.  Здесь также две буквы НН в причастии (от вспахать, приставка, сов.вид).

Возможно, первый вариант больше подходит, так как имеет обобщенный характер, нет указания на завершенность действия.

Comment: Словарь Кузнецова: ПАХАНЫЙ,  Подвергшийся вспашке, возделанный; вспаханный. П-ая земля. П-ое поле. Орфографический словарь Лопатина: паханый, прил., паханный, прич.  Таким образом,  При наличии зависимых слов это причастие (НН), при отсутствии - прилагательное (Н).

Comment: Пардон, неверно прочитал.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно (грамматически и орфоэпически):

1) Глупо есть быку с паханного им поля. 
2) Глупо есть быку со вспаханного им поля.

Что же до выбора канонической формы афоризма, то это самостоятельный вопрос и вряд ли может быть решен однозначно. Мне лично кажется, что бесприставочная форма и несовершенный вид более соответствует афористическому стилю. Но я не нахожу источник афоризма, возможно он закрепился и в другой форме.
(+)===
Тут возник стихийный спор об Н/НН в прилагательных и причастиях. Я сам подзапутался сначала, извиняюсь и исправляюсь.
Если придерживаться стилизации под классическую афористичность (греков, скажем) или библейскую, то НН. Хотя по функциям это все равно прилагательное. Правило о зависимых словах здесь, думаю, использовать неуместно, оно сути не раскрывает. Здесь очевидный признак действия.

Другими словами, даже при отсутствии зависимых слов я написал бы НН. Для "быка" важно не состояние поля, а именно наличие действия по вспашке. Во всяком случае такое следует из комментария автора. Наверное, меня можно побить за нигилизм, но вот стойкое ощущение, что именно так. Настолько стойкое, что даже не сразу понял, что противоречу "шпаргалкам".

**Но в сочетании "паханное им", т. е. быком, спор приобретает чисто академическую окраску, поскольку вожделенное зависимое слово представлено. НН однозначно**

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проще: глупо пахать быку.

Comment: Кто не пашет, тот ест?

Comment: Зачем пахать быку, если трава и так растёт?

Answer (score 0):

Быку, вспахавши поле, травы не кушать боле.

Не видит бык, как вспаханны бразды лишают его, бедного, еды.

Кабы умён был бык, поел бы травки, потом уж перепахивал канавки.

Быку тупому вечно недосуг травы поесть пред тем, как впрячься в плуг.

Comment: Издёвка над быком. Как то не человечно. )